# execute php script upon new google voice text

Tags: php, google-voice

Right now, I have a working PHP script that will pull all my new Google voice texts to perform certain actions. Currently, I have to manually execute the PHP script via computer. More often than not, I am on the road and I need instant changes made to my site. I would like to know how to automatically execute the script as each new text comes in. The goal is to be able to text my Google voice account which will then update my site based on the particular codes I text.

I have thought about meta tag set interval or crontab, but rather than setting an interval of seconds/minutes, I would like to prevent unnecessary calls to the script. Could repeated requests to my Google Voice account flag anyone at Google?

Also, all of the texts can be forwarded to an email. Not sure is it would be easier to begin a script from an email client. If so, please advise.

Like I said the PHP script is already written and working. I just need help determining how to call the script only when a new text or email is received.

Cell -> Google Voice -> PHP -> Website

Comment: Have a look at [Growl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growl_%28software%29), it might be relevant to you.

Comment: Does google voice support HTTP POST? If so, You can make your PHP script listening for POST requests and trigger concerned action based on the text received. You can execute php scripts either using curl or running system commands using http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php OR http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Gearman http://gearman.org/ could do the trick.

It has multy language API so you can just create a worker in php and every time job comes in gearman would call worker to do the job.

Comment: thanks for the input. I'm not sure if I'm ready to tackle another framework, but I'll definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute php scripts either using curl or running console commands using

php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

OR

php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php